# Creating a new column with random dates

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a new column in my data frame with random dates between `01-01-1945` and `01-01-2001`.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
set.seed(123)
df$DOB<-sample(seq(as.Date('1945/01/01'), 
                   as.Date('2001/01/01'), by="day"), length(df$ID))
```

but I am getting this error:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
>     cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'`

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: `length(df$ID)` is greater than the number of days between `01-01-1945` and `01-01-2001`, so it asks you to use `replace = TRUE` so that repetitive dates can be selected. Try, `df$DOB<-sample(seq(as.Date('1945/01/01'), as.Date('2001/01/01'), by="day"), length(df$ID), replace = TRUE)`

Comment: @RonakShah thanks a lot for your detailed explanation.